# SFML with Thor in Fedora 27 Codeblocks

Tags: g++, codeblocks, sfml, fedora, dynamic-linking

Im trying to start a simple game with SFML 2.4 and Thor 2.0 using Code Blocks in C++. 
Im linking dynamically the libraries.

For the Release option on Linker settings tab

```
sfml-audio
sfml-graphics
sfml-window
sfml-system
thor
```

In Search directories -> Compiler:

```
/usr/include
```

In Search directories -> Linker:

```
/usr/lib
```

The game compile well but throw some warnings:

```
||warning: libsfml-graphics.so.2.3, needed by /usr/lib/libthor.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)|
||warning: libsfml-window.so.2.3, needed by /usr/lib/libthor.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)|
||warning: libsfml-system.so.2.3, needed by /usr/lib/libthor.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)|
```

When I run it a window open that says:

```
error while loading shared libraries: libsfml-graphics.so.2.3: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I supose that Thor is searching an old verison of SFML. Any idea how could i correct that?

Note: in /usr/lib/ are there all the libsfml files with the extension 2.4.2 and 2.4 in some cases. Not 2.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The version of Thor you're using is compiled to be used with SFML 2.3, not 2.4. You'll either need to grab the Thor source [from here](https://github.com/Bromeon/Thor) and compile it your self, or get the SFML 2.3 libraries.

Comment: yes!! I recompiled Thor and no more warnings. Now I have this error:  libthor.so: undefined reference to`sf::Image::loadFromFile(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)'

Comment: Now it looks like the SFML version you have and Thor you compiled were not compiled by the same compiler. Make sure you have the right version of SFML for you compiler, and if there isn't a pre-made build, you'll have to compile SFML for youself, then build Thor against that.

Comment: Thanks!! It works. I recompiled everything and goes well.